# Knex JS "OR" Inside .where()?

Tags: javascript, knex.js

Does anyone have any ideea how to write an OR logic like the ' || ' operator in JS
I tried inside my knex to do it like that ->

```
knex('something')
  .where({ state: BOOKING_STATE.ACCEPTED } || { state: BOOKING_STATE.WAITING_LIST})
```

however it fails and i can't find anything about it in the docs

Comment: Can you post your full knex query?

Answer (score 60):

If you check the documentation for `where` clauses with Knex, you'll see a grouped chain where, if you're trying to have multiple where clauses, but only want to `or` the two you listed, then something like this would work.

```
knex('something')
.where(function() {
  this.where('state', BOOKING_STATE.ACCEPTED ).orWhere('state', BOOKING_STATE.WAITING_LIST)
})
.andWhere('something', something_else)
...;
```

Comment: Can we get this as the accepted answer? This is the solutions we needed.

Comment: this also worked for me:  `.where(  (myVal) => { myVal.where.....`
because `this` does not appear to work inside of the arrow function, according to: https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2028

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to use a combination of `where() and orWhere()`:

```
knex('something')
  .where({ state: BOOKING_STATE.ACCEPTED })
  .orWhere({state: BOOKING_STATE.WAITING_LIST })
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see on the [Knex.js Documentation](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-where), it has functions for `where`, `andWhere` and `orWhere`. So you can easily chain your `WHERE` queries by calling

```js
knex('something')
    .where({ state: BOOKING_STATE.ACCEPTED })
    .orWhere({ state: BOOKING_STATE.WAITING_LIST })
```

---

You can also use:

```js
knex.select('some_field').from('some_table')
.where({ state: BOOKING_STATE.ACCEPTED })
.orWhere({ state: BOOKING_STATE.WAITING_LIST })
```